# "The User Profile Service failed the logon. User profile cannot be loaded." on new user

Tags: windows, windows-10, login

I have created new user without connecting it to phone number and to Microsoft account. Now I am wishing to logon as it but failing with a message:

```
The User Profile Service failed the logon. User profile cannot be loaded.
```

The resolutions from here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947215 do not work.

Method #1 fails because I don't have appropriate registry entry.

Method #2 is not applicable, because the user is already new.